# Parse JSON on Classic ASP

Tags: json, asp-classic

How can I get the a JSON Array I get using [ASPJSON v1.17](http://www.aspjson.com/) or [json2.asp](https://github.com/nagaozen/asp-xtreme-evolution/blob/master/lib/axe/classes/Parsers/json2.asp).

```js
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "children":[
      {"id":2},
      {
        "id":7,
        "children":[
          {
            "id":8,
            "children":[
              {"id":9}
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":3,
    "children":[
      {"id":11},
      {"id":12},
      {"id":13},
      {"id":14},
      {"id":15}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":4,
    "children":[
      {"id":16},
      {"id":17},
      {"id":18}
    ]
  },
  {
    "id":5,
    "children":[
      {"id":19},
      {"id":20}
    ]
  },
  {"id":6}
]
```

How to iterate through each member in the loop?

Comment: Check the following site: http://www.aspjson.com

Answer (score 0):

I've experimented with vbs libraries for json and I've come to the conclusion that it's much easier to use js as your scripting language when you're handling json.  I say that as someone who hates js (whether server or client side) and generally avoids using it whenever possible.

Anyway - a very simple example

```
<%@language="javascript"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<h2>JSON ASP Javascript example</h2>
<%
var cars = [{name:'Aston Martin', colour:'Blue'}, {name:'Jaguar', colour:'Silver'}, {name:'Bentley', colour:'Green'}];
for (i in cars)
{ %>
  <%=(cars[i].name) %>, <%=(cars[i].colour) %> <br />
<% } %>

</body>
</html>
```